# Experience Editor error: The item "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/WebEdit Texts" was not found. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: experience-editor

When I am trying to open pages which have Image in the `experience editor` the Image fails to render and I am getting the following error in `Experience Editor`,

```
The item "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/WebEdit Texts" was not found. It may have been deleted by another user.

   at Sitecore.DefaultClient.GetItemNotNull(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.DefaultClient.GetItemNotNull(String itemPath, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.ImageRenderer.GetDefaultImage()
   at Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.ImageRenderer.Render()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue.Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field, Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer)
```

In code we are using the below line to Render the image

```
 @Html.Glass().RenderImage(x =>x.Image, new { W = 120, Width = 120 })
```

I have tried with following code as well

```
 @Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.Image)
```

I verified the logs and found the below error:

> **MediaRequestProtection**: The Media.RequestProtection.SharedSecret
> setting currently uses the default value. It is strongly recommended
> that you change this setting to a random string.
>
> **ERROR** Failed to render field
>
> **Exception**: Sitecore.Exceptions.ItemNullException.

Followed the article
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/protect-media-requests.html and created a patch file as suggested, but still face the same error.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the link database?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to clear the browser cache and open the Experience Editor on the fresh start of your application.

Alternatively, try to open the same site in a different browser that you have not used before.